# Duplicate html with Javascript below the original element

Tags: javascript

I was able to figure out how to duplicate html with javascript. However, I can't figure out how to duplicate the html directly below the original duplicated html. Right now it is going to the bottom of the page.

**Here is my html:**

```
<div id="duplicater"> 
    duplicate EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS DIV
</div>
<button id="button" onlick="duplicate()">Click me</button>
<div class="blank">
    The duplicated info should stay above this.
</div>
```

**Here is my javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;


var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/kXmpY/803/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, in place of `appendChild()`, using `insertBefore()`:

```
original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, original.nextSibling);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jcTrx/).

You could also use `insertAdjacentHTML()`, though frankly it's a little convoluted in this case (since it requires a string of HTML, rather than a DOM node to insert):

```
original.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',clone.outerHTML);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jcTrx/2/).

References:

- [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).
- [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I just gave that a try but now it does not work.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Sorry, I got my references mixed up; it should have been (as it now is) the content to insert followed by the node-reference. Since corrected, and a demo provided.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Comment: Thanks again! Maybe you can help me with one more small issue. I am trying to store this info into a post. However, creating multiple inputs and etc with the same name seems to be causing an issue. Can you help me resolve that? Thanks for any help! Also, how can I remove the extra label names so that only the first one shows? http://jsfiddle.net/kXmpY/808/